# altering theme - content generated by PAGES not PORTFOLIO

Tags: categories, theme-development, themes, tags

I bought the [Hardy theme from Theme Trust](http://themetrust.com/themes/hardy) thinking that the content below the home page slider would be generated by page content NOT "project" or portfolio content.

Turns out, the content below the home page slider is generated by "projects"/portfolio content. I need to make it so that all content below the home page slider is generated by page content; I've contacted Theme Trust support with no luck.

How can I make this happen? I've looked for mention of categories or similar in the index.php but didn't see anything... I'm a bit lost. Ideas?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $show_full_post = of_get_option('ttrust_post_show_full'); ?>
<?php $blog_full_width = of_get_option('ttrust_post_full_width'); ?>
<?php $bw = ($blog_full_width) ? "full" : "twoThirds"; ?>

<?php if(!is_front_page()) : ?>
<div id="pageHead">
    <div class="inside">
    <?php $blog_page_id = of_get_option('ttrust_blog_page'); ?>
    <?php $blog_page = get_page($blog_page_id); ?>
    <h1><?php echo $blog_page->post_title; ?></h1>
    <?php $page_description = get_post_meta($blog_page_id, "_ttrust_page_description", true); ?>
    <?php if ($page_description) : ?>
        <p><?php echo $page_description; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="middle clearfix">
<div id="content" class="<?php echo $bw; ?> clearfix">
    <div id="posts" class="cItems">         
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>             
        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>                    
            <div class="inside">                                                            
                <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="meta clearfix">
                    <?php $post_show_author = of_get_option('ttrust_post_show_author'); ?>
                    <?php $post_show_date = of_get_option('ttrust_post_show_date'); ?>
                    <?php $post_show_category = of_get_option('ttrust_post_show_category'); ?>
                    <?php $post_show_comments = of_get_option('ttrust_post_show_comments'); ?>

                    <?php if($post_show_author || $post_show_date || $post_show_category){ _e('Posted ', 'themetrust'); } ?>                    
                    <?php if($post_show_author) { _e('by ', 'themetrust'); the_author_posts_link(); }?>
                    <?php if($post_show_date) { _e('on', 'themetrust'); ?> <?php the_time( 'M j, Y' ); } ?>
                    <?php if($post_show_category) { _e('in', 'themetrust'); ?> <?php the_category(', '); } ?>
                    <?php if(($post_show_author || $post_show_date || $post_show_category) && $post_show_comments){ echo " | "; } ?>

                    <?php if($post_show_comments) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number(__('No Comments', 'themetrust'), __('One Comment', 'themetrust'), __('% Comments', 'themetrust')); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>                      

                <?php if($show_full_post) : ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php else: ?>

                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                        <?php if(of_get_option('ttrust_post_featured_img_size')=="large") : ?>                                          
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('ttrust_post_thumb_big', array('class' => 'postThumb', 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'')); ?></a>               
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('ttrust_post_thumb_small', array('class' => 'postThumb alignleft', 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'')); ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>         
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <?php more_link(); ?>                   

                <?php endif; ?>         
            </div>                                                                              
        </div>              

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
    <?php global $total_pages; $total_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts/get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>
    <?php $paged = get_query_var('paged'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'part-pagination'); ?> 
</div>


<?php if($bw == "twoThirds") get_sidebar(); ?>              
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: If you paid for a theme I would recommend you contact the developer and ask for the changes. This is something called "after sales".

Comment: @Waldermort That was the first thing I tried; was informed it was beyond the scope of their support services.

Comment: That's the culprit: You can't expect support to also do your customization. You'll need to hire a developer for that. Posting "do this job for me for free" is off topic per the sites FAQ. See the [help].

Comment: @kaiser I apologize if I came off as wanting the work done for free. I attempted this myself first, per the FAQ, and after not quite understanding what to do I decided to ask here for help(eg, the question at the end of my post).

Comment: Well, after a look at the [demo source code](http://themetrust.com/demos/hardy/), I can just say that what you showed above can't be the code that generates the demo page. Sorry, but after ***asking 55 questions*** like this, I can only recommend you to _finally_ learn PHP. You won't get around that and spending a weekend with learning will save you and us a _great_ amount of time. WP.SE simply isn't the place to go and outsource your work :)